# How to use ng class for array of object

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, arrays

I have a case where my response is like below

```
 "currency" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("584aad5d3e2537613e5f4c39"),
        "name" : "USD"
    }
],
```

I want to active my checkbox based on the name

i tried like below

```
ng-class="{'active': vm.settingsObj.currency.name.indexOf('USD') > -1 }"
```

But its not working.Can anyone suggest help .Thanks.

Comment: can your controller do this for you in advance?

Comment: Hi Daniel ,i didnt get you...

Comment: your `vm` could be setup to have the property already calculated.

Comment: What Daniel means is that you should have the controller do the calculation of searching in the array- it's more functionality than normally goes directly in a binding.  You can even wrap the calculation in a method on scope, and then bind the 'active' class to that method directly in your template.

Comment: ok but is there any chanse for doing here

Comment: You should take à look at ng-checked attribute : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

Comment: Try this `ng-class="{'active': vm.settingsObj.currency[0].name == 'USD' }"`.

Answer (score 0):

Does your array only contain 1 item? Because if so, you can do like below:

```
ng-class="{'active': vm.settingsObj.currency[0].name == 'USD' }"
```

Hope it helps =)

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-class="{'active': vm.filter('USD') }"
```

You can set your control in controller

```js
$scope.filter = function(currency){
var json  = { "currency" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "1",
        "name" : "USD"
    },
    {
        "_id" : "2",
        "name" : "EUR"
    }

]};

  
  var res = json.currency.filter(function(elem, index){
  return elem.name == currency
  })
  
  console.log(res)
  console.log(res.length)
  return res.length>0
  
}
```